# It says someone edited 4 minutes ago, but I don't see any changes

Tags: support, edits

I've been trying to figure out one tiny little programming issue for 2 days now. I spent 12 hours yesterday and got nowhere.

So I was excited to see that someone is helping me here on this site. It said that someone edited their response four minutes ago, because I answered their question about my question.

The thing is, I don't see any changes! What happened here?

Answer (score 10):

They edited your question. They didn't post a response.

You can see the changes here  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16048142/revisions

Or by clicking:

[image]

Based upon your recent frustration in this question and your other, which both center around being new to the format, **I highly suggest checking out this tutorial on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/about**

Comment: Yay for tutorials.

Comment: Y U NO FREEHAND CIRCLE?

Comment: Easy! http://i.imgur.com/6cDQwJY.png